# How to install informix on node.js?

Tags: node.js, informix

I try to install informix on node.js via follow from "https://npmjs.org/package/nodejs-db-informix", but it's not success. I don't understand about Pre-req (Setup and configure Informix). I try to install informix on node.js in windows 7. How to solve this problem?

Thank you for help
Lohkaeo

Answer (score -1):

you have to install informix first (I think that's not done yet).
See e.g. http://www.informix-zone.com/getting-started-informix-windows-installing-and-getting-and-running-no-time if you really want to install it on windows..

Then you have to configure the database to be able to access it via nodejs-db-informix...