# Access database informix using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, database, informix

I see this question 2 years ago but any kind of solution [How to install informix on node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971554/how-to-install-informix-on-node-js/).

I'm trying to access informix using nodejs in a Windows enviroment, I try some npm packages but didnt have a good result and others need to be only on Linux.

Thanks for any suggestion, btw need to be in Windows becouse the server.

Comment: IBM has something like their SDK for Node.js, based on the latest community version of Node.js.
Here is the [link](https://developer.ibm.com/node/sdk/)

Comment: The author of ifx_db suggest a new repository: https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxNode

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Informix Native Node.JS driver URL

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ifx_db